# how do I copy and paste images in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how to copy and paste the uploaded images in php.
when i click on copy button then it copy uploaded images.
when click on the paste button then paste that copy image using javascript and php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clicked(){
var src = document.getElementById('copy').value
    document.getElementById('paste').value = src;

}
</script>
```

html:

```
<ul id="image_list">
    <li><img src="elements/1.png" id="copy" width="640px" height = "480px" /></li>

</ul>
<button onclick="clicked();"> Copy </button>
```

Comment: Do you mean copy/paste on the server or on the client?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It's impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: copy and paste images on client side

Answer (score 1):

Check this, this should help you. Someone else already asked this question by the way. Search first, please. :)

```
<script>
function Copy() {
if(window.clipboardData) {
window.clipboardData.clearData();
window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById('txtacpy').value);
} 
}
function paste() {
if(window.clipboardData) {   
document.getElementById('txtapaste').value = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
} 
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:Copy();">Copy</a>
<br />
<input type="text" name="txtacpy" id ="txtacpy"/>
<br />
<a href="javascript:paste();">Paste</a>
<br />
<input type="text" name="txtapaste"  id="txtapaste"/>
```